# cypress after all hook is called before async call completes

Tags: typescript, cypress

In my test I have async function call

```
describe('a', () => {

    after(() => {
        console.log('after call');
    });

    it('a', () => {
        myAsyncFunction().then(() => {
            console.log('async call');
        });
    });

});
```

Looking at console, first is `after call` and then `async call`.

How make `after` be called really after all async calls finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass Mocha's `done()` method and call it inside the async response

```js
describe('a', () => {

    after(() => {
        console.log('after call');
    });

    it('a', (done) => {
        myAsyncFunction().then(() => {
            console.log('async call');
            done();                   // test finishes only after this call is made
                                      // then after() is called
        });
    });

});
```